# Find a string in ansible task output and fail based on presence

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Team, I have below task that is pulling k8s node using label and not finding it returns null in resources. Please observe output, this task is suppose to fail coz it has nothing. so how should i implement fail_when such that when resource list is empty, task should report fail.

```
      - name: "Fetch Dummy label"
        k8s_info:
          kind: Node
          label_selectors:
          - "beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type={{ kube_cpu_node_dummy }}"
          verify_ssl: no
        register: dummy
        failed_when: not dummy
      - debug:
         var: dummy
```

output

```
services-pre-install-checks : debug] ************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 12 December 2019  01:34:33 +0000 (0:00:00.754)       0:00:03.759 *****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "dummy": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "failed_when_result": false,
        "resources": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.. I had to just check if resources is null.

```
  - name: "Fetch Dummy label"
    k8s_info:
      kind: Node
      label_selectors:
      - "beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type={{ kube_cpu_node_dummy }}"
      verify_ssl: no
    register: dummy
    failed_when: not dummy.resources
```